# Retina images: do I need two separate images for small images?

Tags: retina-display

If I have a small PNG file that's maybe 18KB (retina) and 200x80, do I really need to size it in half for a non-retina version? In other words, can't I just do:

```
<img src="images/retina-image.png" width="100" height="40">
```

And then it'll look great on both retina/non-retina devices? Seems like much less work than having two images, and doing this (I'm using Foundation):

```
<img data-interchange="[images/tag.png, (default)], [images/tag@2x.png, (retina)]">
```

I can see why you would do this for images that might be larger in file size, but 18KB is no big deal.

Answer (score 0):

Try it and decide.  The benefits aren't just file size, even on some small images it's worthwhile to shrink things by hand to ensure higher quality than whatever shrinking algorithm the browsers will use.

Comment: It looks OK to me. Though I wonder if on certain operating systems and browsers, using width/height to size down an image might result in poor quality.

Comment: Impact on quality will depends on the contents of the image.  Thin lines or text, for example, are things that could be worth doing the extra work for.